# REST bulk endpoint for fetching data

Tags: api, rest, post, get, endpoint

We(producer for the API) have an endpoint

```
/users/:{id}/name
```

which is used to retrieve name for the user 'id'

Now as a consumer I want to display the list of names for users like:

```
user1: id1, name1
uder2: id2, name2
```

where I have the ids in input.

In such a case should I make 2(here the list is dependent on UI pagination example 50) separate calls to the API to fetch information or else create/ask the producer to create a bulk endpoint like:

```
POST /users/name
body: { ids: []}
```

If later, then am I not loosing the REST principle here to fetch information using POST but not GET? If former, then I am not putting too much network overhead in the system?

Also since this seems to be a very common usecase, if we choose the POST method is there really a need of the GET endpoint since the POST endpoint can handle a single user as well?

Which approach should be chosen?

Answer (score 1):

A GET API call should be used for fetching data. Since browser knows GET calls are idempotent, it can handle some situations on its own, like make another call if previous fails.

Since REST calls are lightweight, we tend to overuse API call repeatedly. In your case, since you want all name v/s id mapping at once, one call is sufficient. Or have a Aggregator endpoint in backend API gateway to reduce network traffic and make repeated calls nearer to actual service.

Keeping GET /users/:{id}/name , is also not a bad idea alongside this. It helps to abstract business functionality. A particular scenario can only allow single fetch.
Also using GET /users/name with pagination and returning list of names is complex for single use so keeping both are fine.